# Fully transparent activity with 9 patch corner image

Tags: android, xml, transparent, nine-patch

In my activity I try to make it transparent and with a 9 patch corner design , but it still showing a black color at the corner there, anyone know how to get rid of it ?

What I try to do here is Non transparent (normal) *Activity A* with start a *new transparent activity B* as shown as below image but the 9patch background with corner design not fully transparent.

[image]

**Here's my 9patch**

[image]

**Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:fadingEdge ="horizontal"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/orange9patch">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="12dip" >
[...........]
```

**Manifest**

```
  <activity android:name=".ui.ResultActivity"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
  </activity>
```

**Style**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
[..........]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">`

instead of yours.