# Shadow on 9 patch

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image: the not working File as Requested]

I have original of this in SVG form
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqAeDSZdzF4WE9vRVZnTVZSRzQ/view?usp=sharing

[Second SVG](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzqAeDSZdzF4ZWpsV2RsS0N4VGM)

[9 patchs left](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzqAeDSZdzF4TmxIaERCQklMMFE) 
[9 patch right](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzqAeDSZdzF4c2xfS2NYWEtMS2M)

I rarely ask questions here. But, maybe someone happens to know a quick fix for this. Should I remake the image or shadow? I rather not to trial and error if it's possible to find an answer. on the right there is a perfect shadow effect like wanted.On the other hand, on left I have this dark grey which doesn't produce a relaible shadow effect. I checked few answers here and did not see any solution. I also don't understand why the right side is good and left side is bad. Maybe it is with the 9 patch quality?
I tried the RGB 8888 and other suggestions from SO and they did not resolve this issue.

[image]

P.S. 
tried this [Fully transparent activity with 9 patch corner image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695834/fully-transparent-activity-with-9-patch-corner-image) and it didn't help either.

Comment: please post the two 9patch files that are displayed in the screenshot

Comment: @sivi share left side 9 patch and right side svg and 9 patch?

Comment: @Anurag, shared

Comment: Thanks will let you know.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @rds The question is why are the shadows of the left side bubble are not  round like in the right side and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ugliest example i could create on my computer:
[image]

it works well, as expected.

You can try uploading it to the [Simple nine-patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) to play with its stretching and contents to see how it behaves.

Comment: What is the blue line? Sorry I'm new to this concepy of 9 patch

Comment: the blue line is supposed to represent the shadow, and this 9patch works in the Simple nine-patch generator  I linked to in my answer. what exactly isn't working for you in thus 9patch?

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the demo project after implementing the same with 9 patch images provided by you. It looks fine. DO let me know if I am missing or update the same project with the problem. [Demo with 9 patch](http://wikisend.com/download/757078/android-RecyclerView-master.zip)

Comment: @sivi Do let me know?

Comment: Sure. In the middle of something else now

Comment: I didn't got to see your project. Were the bubbles fine?

Comment: Yes they are. I don't notice any fault. Update the same project files if you notice the opposite of the same?